# Passing list as function arguments in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to create a linear-gradient using Stylus and the nib extensions. If I pass in separate arguments everything works fine:

`background linear-gradient( 90deg, #000 0%, #FFF 10%, #000 20% )`

However, I need to build up my gradient from within a loop. I'm using a variable and just appending more values onto it:

```
// pseudo-code

grid = 90deg

for percent in percents
  push(grid, #000 percent)

background linear-gradient(grid)
```

I'm running into a problem. The linear-gradient mixin thinks the entire list is one argument, whereas it
is expecting individual color stops. Is there any way to take a list in Stylus and pass it to a function
as multiple arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
linear-gradient()
  unquote('linear-gradient(' + join(', ', arguments) + ')')

percents = 10% 20% 30%

grid = 90deg

for percent in percents
  push(grid, #000 percent)

body
  background linear-gradient(grid)
```

**EXPLANATION**

Well, basically, there is two types of lists in Stylus. The first — expressions, it is a list without commas (e.g. `1 2 3`) and second — lists with commas (e.g. `Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`). And the second type of lists is just the first one but with `isList` internal flag (commas were added on the compilation phase).

Arguments of a function call it is a list of the first type. And currently there is no way to convert a list without commas to a list with commas without looping through items of that list. So, we need to output literally `linear-gradient(<list of arguments with commas>)`, to do it we are using [unquote](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#unquotestr--ident) and [join](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#joindelim-vals) built-in functions.

Comment: Please provide some additional clarification along with your answer because placing just code is not helpful in educating.

Comment: This worked! I agree about maybe putting an edit in with more explanation in case other people are looking for this answer. (the unquote function is the key here.)

Comment: Added an explanation.